# Minecraft PermissionsEX not working

Tags: permissions, yaml, server, minecraft

Ok so my problem is that my minecraft server will not read this so it comes up with no permissions at all. I have typed this from scratch following all of the guide-lines. I have tried altering the big and the small and testing each time and can come up with anything thank, Pokpok300 ~Ben

groups:

```
Player:
    default: 'true'
    options:
        rank: '1000'
        prefix: '&0[&2Player&0]'
    Permissions:
    -essentials.kit
    -essentials.balance
    -essentials.balancetop
    -essentials.pay
    -essentials.afk
    -essentials.afkauto
    -essentials.customtext
    -essentials.help
    -essentials.helpop
    -essentials.mail*
    -essentials.me
    -essentials.msg*
    -essentials.rules
    -essentials.spawn
    -essentials.delhome
    -essentials.home
    -essentials.sethome
    -essentials.tpaccept
    -essentials.tpahere
    -essentials.tpdeny
    -essentials.warp
    -essentials.warp.list

Member:
    inheritance:
    - Player
    options:
        rank: '900'
        prefix: '&0[&3Member&0]'
    Permissions:
    -essentials.ignore
    -essentials.suicide
Member+:
    inheritance:
    - Member
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&3Member+0]'
        rank: '500'
    Permissions:
    -essentials.recipe
    -essentials.enderchest
Trial-Mod:
    inheritance:
    - Member+
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&7Trial-Mod&0]'
        rank: '400'
    Permissions:
    -essentials.tree*
    -essentials.workbench*
    -essentials.realname
    -essentials.whois*
    -essentials.jails
    -essentials.kick
    -essentials.mute*
    -essentials.tempban*
    -essentials.togglejail*
    -essentials.weather
    -essentials.jump
Mod:
    inheritance:
    - Trial-Mod
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&7Mod&0]'
        rank: '300'
    Permissions:
    -essentials.fly*
    -essentials.time*
    -essentials.helpop*
    -essentials.spawner*
    -essentials.invsee*
    -essentials.vanish*
    -essentials.back
    -essentials.sethome.multiple.3
    -essentials.tpaall
    -essentials.world*
Trial-Admin:
    inheritance:
    - Mod
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&1Trial-Admin&0]'
        rank: '200'
    Permissions:
    -essentials.gamemode*
    -essentials.give*
    -essentials.god*
    -essentials.heal*
    -essentials.repair*
    -essentials.unlimited*
    -essentials.ignore*
    -essentials.ban*
    -essentials.banip*
    -essentials.clearinventory*
    -essentials.enderchest*
    -essentials.fireball
    -essentials.kickall*
    -essentials.kill*
    -essentials.remove*
    -essentials.unban*
    -essentials.unbanip*
    -essentials.top*
Admin:
    inheritance:
    - Trial-Admin
    options:
       prefix: '&0[&1Admin&0]'           
       rank: '100'
    Permissions:
    -essentials.exp*
    -essentials.feed*
    -essentials.more*
    -essentials.speed*
    -essentials.powertool*
    -essentials.powertooltoggle*
    -essentials.backup*
    -essentials.broadcast
    -essentials.deljail
    -essentials.setjail
    -essentials.setspawn
    -essentials.delwarp
    -essentials.sethome*
    -essentials.tpall*
    -essentials.tphere*
    -essentials.tpo*
    -essentials.tpohere*
    -essentials.tppos*
    -essentials.tptoggle*
Co-Owner:
    inheritance:
    - Admin
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&6Co-Owner&0]'            
        rank: '50'
    Permissions:
Owner:
    inheritance:
    - Co-Owner
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&9Owner&0]'            
        rank: '1'
    Permissions: 
    -essentials.nuke*
Dontator:
    inheritance:
    - Member+
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&2Dontator&0]'        
    Permissions:
    -essentials.workbench*
    -essentials.recipe
Dontator+:
    inheritance:
    - Dontator
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&2Dontator+&0]'        
    Permissions:
    -essentials.nick
    -essentials.nick.color
Dontator++:
    inheritance:
    - Dontator++
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&2Dontator++&0]'        
    Permissions: 
    -essentials.nick
    -essentials.nick.color
    -essentials.nick.magic
    -essentials.nick.format
CustomDontator:
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&2Dontator+++&0]'        
    Permissions:
```

Comment: Can you specify the exact problem? Or at leat paste the server log.

Comment: So I found out anyone who has this same problem there must be a space after -essentials.kit to create - essentials.kit this must be done for all permissions.

Comment: Also the server logs did not show up any different the plugin just was not active.

Comment: Use Essentials Group Manager instead...it is much more organized and will likely work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are new at this... So I fixed everything up!

```
groups:
    Player:
    default: 'true'
    options:
        rank: '1000'
        prefix: '&0[&2Player&0]'
    permissions:
    - essentials.kit
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.balancetop
    - essentials.pay
    - essentials.afk
    - essentials.afk.auto
    - essentials.customtext
    - essentials.help
    - essentials.helpop
    - essentials.mail.*
    - essentials.me
    - essentials.msg.*
    - essentials.rules
    - essentials.spawn
    - essentials.delhome
    - essentials.home
    - essentials.sethome
    - essentials.tpaccept
    - essentials.tpahere
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.warp
    - essentials.warp.list

Member:
    inheritance:
    - Player
    options:
        rank: '900'
        prefix: '&0[&3Member&0]'
    permissions:
    - essentials.ignore
    - essentials.suicide
Member+:
    inheritance:
    - Member
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&3Member+0]'
        rank: '500'
    Permissions:
    - essentials.recipe
    - essentials.enderchest
Trial-Mod:
    inheritance:
    - Member+
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&7Trial-Mod&0]'
        rank: '400'
    permissions:
    - essentials.tree
    - essentials.workbench
    - essentials.realname
    - essentials.whois
    - essentials.jail
    - essentials.kick
    - essentials.mute
    - essentials.tempban
    - essentials.togglejail
    - essentials.weather
    - essentials.jump
Mod:
    inheritance:
    - Trial-Mod
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&7Mod&0]'
        rank: '300'
    permissions:
    - essentials.fly
    - essentials.time
    - essentials.helpop
    - essentials.spawner
    - essentials.invsee
    - essentials.vanish
    - essentials.back
    - essentials.sethome.multiple.3
    - essentials.tpaall
    - essentials.world
Trial-Admin:
    inheritance:
    - Mod
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&1Trial-Admin&0]'
        rank: '200'
    permissions:
    - essentials.gamemode
    - essentials.give
    - essentials.god
    - essentials.heal
    - essentials.repair
    - essentials.unlimited
    - essentials.ignore
    - essentials.ban
    - essentials.banip
    - essentials.clearinventory
    - essentials.enderchest
    - essentials.fireball
    - essentials.kickall
    - essentials.kill
    - essentials.remove
    - essentials.pardon
    - essentials.pardonip
    - essentials.top
Admin:
    inheritance:
    - Trial-Admin
    options:
       prefix: '&0[&1Admin&0]'           
       rank: '100'
    permissions:
    - essentials.exp
    - essentials.feed
    - essentials.more
    - essentials.speed
    - essentials.powertool
    - essentials.powertooltoggle
    - essentials.backup
    - essentials.broadcast
    - essentials.deljail
    - essentials.setjail
    - essentials.setspawn
    - essentials.delwarp
    - essentials.sethome
    - essentials.tpall
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.tpahere
    - essentials.tppos
    - essentials.tptoggle
Co-Owner:
    inheritance:
    - Admin
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&6Co-Owner&0]'            
        rank: '50'
    permissions:
Owner:
    inheritance:
    - Co-Owner
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&9Owner&0]'            
        rank: '1'
    Permissions: 
    - essentials.nuke
Dontator:
    inheritance:
    - Member+
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&2Dontator&0]'
        default: false   
    Permissions:
    - essentials.workbench
    - essentials.recipe
Dontator+:
    inheritance:
    - Dontator
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&2Dontator+&0]'
        default: false      
    permissions:
    - essentials.nick
    - essentials.nick.color
Dontator++:
    inheritance:
    - Dontator++
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&2Dontator++&0]'
        default: false     
    permissions: 
    - essentials.nick
    - essentials.nick.color
    - essentials.nick.magic
    - essentials.nick.format
CustomDontator:
    options:
        prefix: '&0[&2Dontator+++&0]'
        default: false     
    Permissions:
```

Comment: I and welcome to SO! Could you add comments explaining the changes you've made? Thanks!

Comment: Well... When you wrote a permission nose -essentials.help your needed a space "- essentials.help" also there were a couple *s that weren't in the right place! So I fixed that up??? Is everything good?

Comment: I meant permission nodes!